# Good Probability Theory Textbook for Computer Science

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, computer-science

Context:

I am a rising CS senior planning on going for a PhD. I would like to study probability theory on my own for its usefulness in machine learning and game theory. There are quite a few textbooks out there, so I would like a recommendations on books that have good coverage on stuff relevant in CS.

I was thinking of going either with [Probability Theory: The Logic of Science by Jaynes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521592712) or with [Introduction to Probability by Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/188652940X). Both seem to be received very positively, but I don't know if I should go with these or another textbook written with applications in mind.

Comment: Are you looking at foundational mathematics of machine learning (using measure theory, probably approximately correct, etc...) or more applied statistical learning theory?

Comment: I'm looking for the former, but with a somewhat broader perspective than just what is currently utilized by machine learning techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My probability class used the second one and it covers all the basics while getting into estimation, inference and some stochastic processes.  I personally liked it and several of my friends used it to prepare for out machine learning classes.